# How do I get notified when someone creates a new Repository in Gitlab?

Tags: notifications, gitlab, repository

I need to be notified when someone creates a new Repository in a group (or in the instance) of my gitlab. I want only to be notified on new repositories, not all pull requests, merges, etc.

I have tried:

1. Creating a Project Template that e-mails me when it is used. This should have worked but Projects do not run a pipeline when created from a template.
2. Checking Webhooks. Webhooks provide the option to be notified on a number of things but not Repository Creation Specifically
3. Checking Notifications. Similar to Webhooks.
4. Extensively searching on google for anything related to creating new Repositories and notifications or triggering

There has to be some easier way to do this than setting up a service to constantly pull the list of projects and alert when it is different. Gitlab must have an integration for notifications about New Repositories.

Answer (score 1):

[System hooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/system_hooks.html) can be used to hook into a number of system events, including `project_create` events for the instance.

This feature is only available on self-managed GitLab instances and can only be configured by administrators.

Comment: Can't help to wonder. Why is this not possible for Gitlab service at group owner levels.